# ZOHO API v2 Insert Lead with Guzzle 6.2 (Laravel) using API records

Tags: laravel, zoho, guzzle6

I want to insert new leads generated from an HTML form into Zoho CRM (https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/insert-records.html).

**Creating Guzzle client:**

```
$client = new Client([
    'headers'  => [ 'Authorization' => 'Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $this->accessToken ], // $this->accessToken checks for a valid access tokens en refreshes it if (almost) expired
    'base_uri' => $this->configuration['endpoint'], // https://www.zohoapis.eu/crm/v2/ 
]);
```

**The Json code to insert (simplified for testing)**

`{"data":[{"Last_Name":"Test name"}]}` (content of $lead)

**When I post this with Guzzle:**

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'Leads', [
    'json' =>  $lead
]);
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Client error: `POST https://www.zohoapis.eu/crm/v2/Leads` 
resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"code":"INVALID_DATA","details":
{"expected_data_type":"jsonobject"},"message":"body","status":"error"}
```

Answer (score 0):

for more help, if you are aware of the POSTMAN then there is ZOHO CRM Postman Collection.

for JSON Object error- simple Create MAP and pass as a parameter.